# Login with my launchpad profile on Ubuntu One is possible?

Tags: ubuntu-one, single-sign-on

Does any one know if I can logon into **Ubuntu One** using my launchpad.net profile (openid)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, it's called Ubuntu Single Sign On:

[image]